# HTML5 form is not getting submitted

Tags: html, forms, submit

I have the following code to submit a form. If I use the event listener function name as submit, the form does not get submitted. If I use any other name, it will. Should not I use any HTML5 keyword like **submit** in JavaScript as function name? In this case **submit** is a HTML5 keyword which can be used as a type of any **INPUT** element.

```
<form onsubmit="submit()">
    <input type="email" name="email" />
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>

function submit() {
    var f = $('form').serialize();
    alert(f);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using ** as prefix and suffix to your submit function call? I have never seen that before. Mayby try to remove them first:)

Comment: I'm sorry. I removed the ** from the event listener. That was added by StackOverflow when I tried to bold the function name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already using jQuery here so a more elegant solution to the whole problem would be:

```
// HTML
<form name="my-form">
    <input type="email" name="email" />
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Then have a separate JS file:

```
//Js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form[name="my-form"]').submit(function(e){
        var f=$(this).serialize();
        alert(f);
    });
});
```

This also gives you extra options to prevent the form from submitting cleanly; add this at the end of the `submit(){ }` function.

```
e.preventDefault();
```

#### Update

As the *OP* pointed out the original question was whether the function name `submit()` can be used as the `onsubmit` attribute in a form.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25222777/518703) suggests that it cannot, as carrying out the following:

```
document.form['my-form'].submit();
```

Would be a valid way to trigger submission of the form; thus that method name can't then be included in the HTML. *I am searching now for a better source to confirm this for sure* I have found a similar source on [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.submit) which confirms the code above but doesn't explicitly define that the keyword `submit` cannot be used.

Comment: I may be able to achieve whatever I wanted with the code that you submitted. However, my question was around using HTML5 keywords in JavaScript.

Comment: Ah understood. It's not related to the HTML5 specification; `onsubmit` has been a form attribute for a while, which is what made me think you were asking the wider question.

Answer (score 0):

You know, there is another way to do this. You could separate your html from javascript enritelly.

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="email" name="email" />
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
//Rest of your code
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#form').submit(function() {
        var f = $('#form').serialize();
        // do your stuff
        return true; // return false to cancel form action
    });
});
</script>
```